# Binding shared service in two directives

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

What I want to accomplish is to bind two directives throw a shared service so that when there are changes in one of them, immediately the change will propagate to the other.

My directives looks like this:

```
app.directive("input1", function (sharedService) {
    return  {
        restict: 'A',
        scope: 'isolate',
        template: '<input type="text" ng-model="sharedText" class="input-medium" />{{sharedText}}',
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
            scope.sharedText = sharedService.sharedText; // Service never gets updated if the scope it's modified :(
        }
    }
});

app.directive("input2", function (sharedService) {
    return  {
        restict: 'A',
        scope: 'isolate',
        template: '<input type="text" ng-model="sharedText" class="input-medium" />{{sharedText}}',
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
            scope.sharedText = sharedService.sharedText;
        }
    }
});
```

Here you can see a fiddle of what I have till now: `http://jsfiddle.net/Hubrus/kxGG6/1/`

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `.` notation or object due to prototypal nature of code. Direct string binding create a new string value on the current scope.

See this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/TAhfb/2/